# Make sure that only one radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I need to make a check that only one radio button (out of two) is checked. Normally you would add the same name="something" on all the radio buttons in the group, but in this case they don't have the same name - and unfortunately, I can't change that.

How can I make a check that only one is selectable at the time using their ids or different names?

I have [fiddled a bit here](http://jsfiddle.net/mHc3v/3/), but I don't know how to make it work:

```
var check1 = $('#one');
var check2 = $('#two');
var allChecks = check1,
    check2;

allChecks.change(function () {
    allChecks.each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', !$(this).attr('checked'));
    });
    return false;
});
```

And:

```
<input type="radio" name="one" id="one">
<input type="radio" name="two" id="two">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this without modify your html:

```
$("#one").change(function(){

       $("#two").prop("checked", false);

});
$("#two").change(function(){

       $("#one").prop("checked", false);

});
```

Comment: As for jq 1.6 version, preferred method is to use `prop()`, not `attr()`

Answer (score 2):

You could set a common class to all radios targeted and use:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVCaJ/)

```
$(".cradio").change(function () {
   $('.cradio').not(this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="one" id="one" class="cradio">
<input type="radio" name="two" id="two" class="cradio">
```

Comment: ... or if adding a class isn't an option too, you can instead do `$('#one, #two').change....`

Comment: @frnhr correct, even i don't see why adding a class couldn't be an option